# React + Typescript. Render proper Icon based on dynamic props value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a span in my JSX in which I want to render a proper icon based on the dynamic props value

```
<span>{IconToProductMap(value)}</span>
```

This is how this function looks like

```
const IconToProductMap = (value: string) => {
  if (value === 'sampleValue') {
    return <Icon type={IconType.card} />
  }
  if (value === 'sampleValue2') {
    return <Icon type={IconType.card2} />
  }
  return <Icon type={IconType.card3} />
}
```

This solution is really bad and
I'd like to be able to dynamically assign the value so that I can render the icon like this

```
    <span>{IconToProductMap[value]}</span>
```

To achieve that I've created the mapper object

```
const mapper = {
  possiblePropsValue1: IconType.card,
  possiblePropsValue2: IconType.bag,
  possiblePropsValue3: IconType.arrow_left,
}
```

and used it like so:

```
    <span>{mapper[value]}</span>
```

The problem is that TS throws

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type '{ possiblePropsValue1: IconType;
> possiblePropsValue2: IconType; possiblePropsValue3: IconType; }'.   No
> index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{
> possiblePropsValue1: IconType; possiblePropsValue2: IconType;
> possiblePropsValue3: IconType; }'

Could someone explain me how to properly fix that?

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define `mapper` with a proper type

```
const mapper: Record<string, JSX.Element> = {
  possiblePropsValue1: IconType.card,
  possiblePropsValue2: IconType.bag,
  possiblePropsValue3: IconType.arrow_left,
}
```

[`Record<key,value>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) receives `key` as string, `value` as `JSX.Element` which is from your `IconType` returned value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) to simplify string parameters & better manage the icon types. You can store the strings (`sampleValue`) in the enum.

```
enum IconType {
  card = "card",
  bag = "bag",
  arrow_left = "arrow_left"
}

interface IconProps {
  iconType: IconType;
}

const Icon = (props: IconProps) => {
  const { iconType } = props;
  return <div>{iconType}</div>; // just for demonstration
};

export default function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Icon iconType={IconType.bag} />
    </div>
  );
}
```